# Constraint Satisfaction Problem for round-robin pairings and odd number of teams

Tags: python, constraints, or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

I am trying to model a CSP to generate round-robin pairings/matchups in a sports league using [Google OR-Tools CP-SAT Solver](https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_solver).

The tool will take two parameters: number of teams and number of games each team should play. The expected result is a schedule where teams are paired "evenly".

The problem is modelled as a 3-dimensional structure with boolean values: if `pairings[g][i][j]` means *team i* plays *team j* in their *game g*. Note that this also implies home and away positions. This is how the model is created:

```
# team i plays team j on game g
for g in self.games:
    self.pairings.append([])
    for i in self.teams:
        self.pairings[g].append([])
        for j in self.teams:
            self.pairings[g][i].append(self.model.NewBoolVar('{}v{} [#{}]'.format(i, j, g + 1)))
            if i == j:
                # team cannot play self
                self.model.Add(self.pairings[g][i][j] == 0)
```

It works great, *except* when the number of teams is odd.

There are several constraints enforcing the following and they all seem to work in all cases (even or odd number of teams; edit: except when both number of teams and games are odd):

- *total number of games* each team plays. (Not necessary but helps reinforce the model)
- *round-robin constraint* enforces that every "round" each team play every other. For example if we have 5 teams and 10 games, games are "split" in 4/4/2 rounds and the constraint ensures that every team plays every other exactly once in the first two rounds and once, *at most*, in the last one (since it's not a perfect round).
- *number of match-ups constraint* enforces the number of times every team play each other. (Not necessary as it's indirectly introduced by the round-robin constraint but helps reinforce the model)
- *number of home/away constraint* enforces that teams get a balanced number of home and away number of games, for example 5 home and 5 away if they play 10 games, or 3 home and 4 away if they play 7 games.
- *maximum number of consecutive home/away games constraint* aims at a balanced home/away spread by enforcing that there cannot be more than 2 consecutive home or consecutive away games. I tried having this as no more than 1 consecutive sequence but apparently this is mathematically impossible? The model would always be infeasable.

There is one more key constraint which is the one I pinned as problematic with odd number of teams:

- *one opponent constraint* ensures that for each game, *team i* plays *team j* exactly once, either as home or as away.

This is how it's modelled:

```
# ensure that a game occurs: each game, team i plays team j exactly once as i vs j or as j vs i
for g in self.games:
    for i in self.teams:
        opponents = []
        for j in self.teams:
            if i == j:
                continue
            opponents.append(self.pairings[g][i][j])
            opponents.append(self.pairings[g][j][i])
        self.model.Add(sum(opponents) == 1)
```

This constraint make schedules with odd number of teams infeasable. When turned off, a solution is found but I get "unbalanced" schedules, such as:

```
Schedule (6 teams; 5 games):
Game 1: (0, 5) (1, 5) (2, 4) (4, 1)
Game 2: (3, 2) (4, 0)
Game 3: (0, 3) (1, 0)
Game 4: (0, 2) (3, 5)
Game 5: (2, 1) (3, 1) (4, 3) (5, 2) (5, 4)
```

And it also messes up even number of team schedules:

```
Schedule (8 teams; 8 games):
Game 1: (0, 2) (4, 5) (7, 3)
Game 2: (0, 7) (1, 0) (2, 5) (2, 6) (3, 4) (4, 6) (5, 7) (6, 0) (7, 1)
Game 3: (3, 1)
Game 4: (0, 3) (1, 4) (7, 2)
Game 5: (3, 5) (5, 6) (6, 1) (6, 7)
Game 6: (1, 5) (2, 4) (3, 6) (4, 0) (4, 7) (5, 0)
Game 7: (1, 2) (2, 3)
Game 8: (0, 3) (5, 4) (6, 2) (7, 1)
```

That otherwise would look nice and clean like this:

```
Schedule (8 teams; 8 games):
Game 1: (1, 0) (5, 3) (6, 4) (7, 2)
Game 2: (0, 5) (2, 1) (3, 6) (4, 7)
Game 3: (0, 2) (4, 3) (5, 6) (7, 1)
Game 4: (1, 5) (2, 4) (3, 7) (6, 0)
Game 5: (0, 3) (1, 4) (2, 6) (5, 7)
Game 6: (3, 2) (4, 5) (6, 1) (7, 0)
Game 7: (0, 4) (2, 5) (3, 1) (6, 7)
Game 8: (1, 6) (4, 3) (5, 0) (7, 2)
```

Can you help me understand why this isn't working with odd number of teams? Is this a inherent mathematical issue? Or there is a way around it?

The only solution I've thought of is adding a "bye" team and an extra game for each team, but that messes up the whole round-robin and home/away balance since we're adding a team and games that aren't real.

I also tried changing the one opponent constraint to `self.model.Add(sum(opponents) <= 1)` since with odd number of teams a game might not happen since it's a bye, but it also comes up as infeasable.

PS: if you are interested in the entire code I can link a gist. It's under 200 lines of code.

edit: new development: if the number of teams is odd and number of games is also odd, the schedule is unfeasable even when all constraints are turned off except the *total number of games constraint*, which is implemented as follows:

```
for i in self.teams:
    games = []
    for g in self.games:
        for j in self.teams:
            if i == j:
                continue
            games.append(self.pairings[g][i][j])
            games.append(self.pairings[g][j][i])
    self.model.Add(sum(games) == self.num_games)
```

Which I guess makes sense because if you try pairing teams you always end up with 1 game short or extra. Is this related to the main issue? How do I deal with this?